# How to Switch "like button" using js in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, toggle

I have implemented like button in my Django project, everything is working fine except like and dislike button aren't switching after clicking on them, to change I have to refresh the whole page!
how to make dislike button display immediately after liking it and vice versa?

Here's the code

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <strong id="like_count">{{ post.likes }}</strong> people like this category

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <button id="likes" data-post_id="{{post.id}}"  class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
        </button>

{% endif %}
</p>
```

**JS**

```
$('#likes').click(function(){
    var postid;
    postid= $(this).attr("data-post_id");
    $.get('/blog/like_post/', {post_id: postid}, function(data){
               $('#like_count').html(data);
               $('#likes').hide();
    });
});
$('#likes').click(function() {
    $('#display_advance').toggle('1000');
    $("i", this).toggleClass("glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up");
});
```

Thank you

Comment: What has this to do with Django?

Comment: I'm using this in my django project

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with `$("i", this)`. What is this? I see no `i` tag inside.

Secondly, when you `.toggleClass("glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up")`, I think you shouldn't list both thumbs-down and thumbs-up. Instead, you should have 2 statements

`.toggleClass("glyphicon-thumbs-up")
.toggleClass("glyphicon-thumbs-down")`

PS: It's not related to Django, it's just jquery
PS2: why do you have 2 consecutive click events on `#likes`?

Answer (score 0):

I find simple to be best... run this in a fiddle and experiment.

```
<button id="acceptMe" onclick="hideAccept();">Accept</button>
<button id="rejectMe" onclick="hideReject();">Reject</button>

<script>
function hideAccept(){
document.getElementById("acceptMe").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("rejectMe").style.display="block";
}

function hideReject(){
document.getElementById("rejectMe").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("acceptMe").style.display="block";
}
</script>
```